# Liquid truncate text in Jekyll post

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

How can i truncate only text (paragraphs) exceeding limit of 1000 bytes, ignoring for example img and script tags?

To get correct post size, i'm using this:

```
{% assign count = page.content | strip_html %}
```

But to cut text i tried truncate and truncate words filters, in both ways it will cut everything over the limit.

Any ideas?